# How to create ubuntu installation preseed file

Tags: system-installation, preseed

I am manually installing Ubuntu on the laptop from USB drive (ISO image).  I would like to record my answers to the installation questions(language, keyboard layout, disk partitioning etc) and create pressed file (which feeds d-i answers to questions normally asked by debconf) to be used in the future to automate installation on identical/similar laptops/netbooks.

Answer (score 8):

I've found this:

http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.automated-installation.html

Which gives me:

```
sudo apt-get install debconf-utils
sudo debconf-get-selections --installer
```

the later will dump the answered question in preseed's format, still a lot of garbage in the output. But the answer seems here.

execute it without root level to see the path of answer file, for me:

```
/var/log/installer/cdebconf/questions.dat
```

Some link(s) I've found, not enough reputation to post more ;)

- [How to automate Debian installs with Preseed](http://web.archive.org/web/20160328043818/http://fak3r.com/2011/08/18/howto-automate-debian-installs-with-preseed/)

At the bottom of this page you will find most of the main links to become a preseed master.

Comment: This is not working on Ubuntu 18.10 :(

Comment: @vikas027 preseeding is _very much_ a distro _and_ release specific thing. The only way to work this out is by checking your preseed file against a new release _or_ by looking for resources from others who have pioneered something like that for your desired Ubuntu release, e.g. [here](https://github.com/panticz/preseed). And even if these may not provide canned solutions, they may turn out to be quite inspirational with respect to tricks you can use during preseeding.